# What material are older soft (plant) parts made of?

Tags: manufacturing, plastics

I've carefully searched through SE and web and haven't found the exact answer.

[This 2018 announcement](https://www.lego.com/en-dk/aboutus/news/2019/october/lego-plants-made-from-plants/) states that new plant parts are made of plant-based *polyethylene*. It also implies that plant parts used to be made of polyethylene too, but it's just a hint though. I've also encountered some sources on the web mentioning *polypropylene* as the material.

Here are the examples of parts which seem to be manufactured of the same sort of plastic:

- 2518 Tree Palm Leaf Large 10 x 5

[image: 2518 Tree Palm Leaf Large 10 x 5]

- 2536x Tree Palm Trunk

[image: 2536x Tree Palm Trunk]

- 2542 Paddle

[image: 2542 Paddle]

- 30158 Backpack Opening

[image: 30158 Backpack Opening]

So now I wonder which material soft parts (plants and similar) are made of prior to the 2018 announcement of switching to plant-based polyethylene.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Brickset](https://brickset.com/article/37274/review-40320-plants-from-plants), these parts have always been made of polyethylene, the only difference is that some of the material is plant-based since the *Plants from Plants* initiative.

> **Can you tell the difference?**
>
> No! They look, feel, smell and work just like 'regular' botanical elements. This is because, chemically, they are the same. You can safely mix them with your other plant pieces safe in the knowledge that there is no difference.

Comment: The material is clearly named in the article. Thank you!